# dependent parameters in multiple Angular GET requests

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

An Angular function has two HTTP GET requests, A and B. Request A is returning data X, and request B is returning data Y. Both X and Y are constantly changing in the backend. This function needs to display the variable (X+Y)/2 in real time. what do you do?

Comment: What did you try so far? What is blocking you?

Comment: @GaëlJ I have got this query and need to implement but haven't explored the way forward.

Comment: Please do some initial exploration and research before asking on Stack Overflow. If you don't know about them, I suggest learning about subscriptions, polling, and websockets.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using rxjs zip operator, that emit an array of value when both of your calls emit values

```
import { zip } from 'rxjs';
import { take, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

zip(call1, call2).pipe(
 take(1),
 map((dataArray) => // you can sum the 2 values of your dataArray and devide by 2  )
).subscribe(console.log)
```